# MonoDevelop does not start under Raspbian on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mono, monodevelop, raspberry-pi, raspbian

MonoDevelop during the launch throws error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object at
>   MonoDevelop.Ide.IdePreferences.get_DefaultTargetRuntime () [0x00000]
>   in :0 at MonoDevelop.Ide.RootWorkspace.set_UseDefaultRuntime (Boolean
>   value) [0x00000] in :0 at MonoDevelop.Ide.RootWorkspace..ctor ()
>   [0x00000] in :0 at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Initialize (IProgressMonitor
>   monitor) [0x00000] in :0 at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run
>   (MonoDevelop.Ide.MonoDevelopOptions options) [0x00000] in :0

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Debian image provided on the Raspberry Pi website, although it is not as optimized as the Raspbian image it does have better compatibility with some applications which are not fully supported or working.